# removing appended code is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have appended checkboxes on a button click it works fine but after appending removing those by another button click is not at all working.I need someone to checkout and help.

```js
$(".btn").on('click', function(){
    $('#Locations').append('<div id="mydiv">' +
                       '<input type="button" value="-" class="rmvbtn">' +
                       '<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" />' +
    $(".txt").val() +
     "</br>............</br>" +
     '</div>');
});

$(".rmvbtn").click(function(){
    $('#mydiv').remove();
});
```

Comment: Try $("#mydiv").html(""); Can you post some of you html as well?

Comment: when i press the rmvbtn button,it is not even going to the function specified for it when clicked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently what you are using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach to element that exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

You need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach, when generating elements dynamically or manipulation selector (like removing and adding classes).

*General Syntax*

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

*As per your code*

```js
$('#Locations').on("click", ".rmvbtn", function(){
    $('#mydiv').remove();
});
```

```js
$(".btn").on('click', function(){
    $('#Locations').append('<div id="mydiv">' +
                       '<input type="button" value="-" class="rmvbtn">' +
                       '<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" />' +
    $(".txt").val() +
     "</br>............</br>" +
     '</div>');
});

$('#Locations').on("click", ".rmvbtn", function(){
    $('#mydiv').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">Create</button>
<div id="Locations"></div>
```